# How to get the screen refresh rate?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

Is this even possible? Since ive noticed v-sync doesnt work on my laptop at all, so i am building FPS limiter "manually" and now i would like to use the FPS limit the user has set to his screen.

**Edit:** i mean the monitor hz rate.

**Edit3:** heres the code i got working (i think... anything wrong there?):

```
DEVMODE lpDevMode;
memset(&lpDevMode, 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));
lpDevMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
lpDevMode.dmDriverExtra = 0;

if(EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &lpDevMode) == 0){
    framerate_limit = 60; // default value if cannot retrieve from user settings.
}
```

On demand, here is my v-sync enabling code jay.lee asked for:

```
PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC wglSwapIntervalEXT = NULL; // global

...

wglSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT");

v_sync_enabled = 0;
if(wglSwapIntervalEXT != NULL){
    if(wglSwapIntervalEXT(1) != FALSE){
        v_sync_enabled = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the Hz rate of the monitor, and not your drawing loop?

Comment: just curious, how are you trying to enable vsync?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The Win32 `EnumDisplaySettings` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611(v=VS.85).aspx) could be what you're looking for.  The refresh rate is held in `lpDevMode->dmDisplayFrequency`.